# Non-zero nilpotent operator

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

I know that if an operator $T\in L(V)$ is nilpotent, then $T^{dim(V)}=0$.

I am struggling to construct an example of a nilpotent operator $T\in L(V)$ which satisfies the condition $T^{dim(V)-1}\neq 0$.

Is there a such example?

It would be great if someone could explain in detail.

Comment: “Example 1” in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix, or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_matrix.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you but I do not quite get why that  could be an example. Can you explain?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. What is $N$ and how is it related to $T$?

Comment: @MartinR sorry there was a typo and I just edited it.

Comment: Example 1 is: $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A^1 \ne 0$, $A^2 = 0$. The shift matrix is the generalization to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. Can you give me an example for 3x3 matrix?
So I can piture the concept better?

Comment: Have a look at the “shift matrix” $S$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix#Classification.

Comment: @MartinR I got the idea now!

Answer (score 0):

The [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) $C$ of $X^n$ has $X^n$ as its minimal polynomial. Therefore, $C^n=0$ but $C^{n-1}\ne0$.